# Cross compare two sets of data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, csv

I have a report table.  A report can have many documents (which are csv file paths).  A document has many mappings.

So I initially loop my documents for a report and load the csv data using [ParseCsv](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php)

```
foreach ($this->report->uploadedDocuments->documents as $document) {
    $csv = new ParseCsv\Csv();
    $csv->limit = 1;
    $csv->parse(storage_path("app/" . $document->fullName));
    $this->csvData = $csv->data;
}
```

If I output this, I see something like the following for each document (only showing one CSV row here from one document)

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "field1":"Some data",
      "something":"Some data",
      "something":"Some data",
      "something":"Some data",
      "something":"Some data",
   }
]
```

Now each document has mappings so I can also do something like this

```
foreach ($this->report->uploadedDocuments->documents as $document) {
    
    //Load CSV data
    
    foreach ($document->mappings as $column) {
        Log::debug(json_encode($column));
    }
}
```

The output for the above is something like this

```
{
   "document_id":"6434fc74-18f7-43ff-be33-3a8b0cf1cadc",
   "field1":1,
   "field2":null,
   "field3":null,
   "created_at":"2020-10-26T10:19:36.000000Z",
   "updated_at":"2020-10-26T10:19:36.000000Z"
}
```

So from the above, I can see that field1 is located in column (index) 1 in the csv data.  I can also see that this CSV does not have a field2 or field3.  So my idea is to turn the original CSV data into this

```
[
   {
      "field1":"Some data",
   }
]
```

So this is my thinking.  I first need to loop the documents for the reports, load the CSV files, and read the data

```
foreach ($this->analysis->uploadedDocuments->documents as $document) {
    $csv = new ParseCsv\Csv();
    $csv->limit = 5;
    $csv->parse(storage_path("app/" . $document->fullName));

    if (empty($csv->data)) {
        throw new Exception('Not data found in file.');
    }

    foreach ($csv->data as $dataKey => &$item) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
            //Now I have access to the keys and values from csv
        }
    }
}
```

But then how can I cross check this against my document mappings?  I obviously have to loop the mappings but where should I do this?  I have something which I think could work but it is very messy, and relies on my knowing the column names e.g.

```
foreach ($this->report->uploadedDocuments->documents as $document) {
    $csv = new ParseCsv\Csv();
    $csv->limit = 5;
    $csv->parse(storage_path("app/" . $document->fullName));

    if (empty($csv->data)) {
        throw new Exception('Not data found in file.');
    }
    
    foreach ($document->mappings as $column) {
        foreach ($csv->data as $dataKey => &$item) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                //match the mapping column to the csv column
                if ($column->fieldOne !== NULL && $key === $column->fieldOne) {
                    //now I have access to the values for that column
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would there be a better way of achieving something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following as I understand from your question

```
<?PHP
 $csvData = $csv->data;
 $csvData = json_encode($csvData);
 $arr = json_decode($csvData, true);
 $field1 = array_column($arr, "field1");
 print_r($field1);
?>
```

This line convert object into json string
$csvData = json_encode($csvData);

This line convert json string to pure array
$arr = json_decode($csvData, true);

This line extract column value from multidimensional array
$field1 = array_column($arr, "field1");

**I hope this will work.**

Comment: Made some slight adjustments but it helped me with what I needed to achieve, thanks

Comment: Thanks, nice to hear that.